# Django registration URL

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new at Django so maybe this problemlooks silly for professionals. I'm trying to make simple registration form for user. I'm using UserCreationForm and got one problem I can reach my registration form by address: mydomain.com/accounts/register is it possible to change that adress to mydomain.com?

views.py

`def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/books/")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, "index.html",{"form": form})`

Comment: Sure. Can you post your current urls.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just make corresponding alterations in your urls.py

And this line

```
new_user = form.save()
```

looks a bit odd. You don't create/save a new user instance this way - you only save your UserCreationForm object.

Comment: Actually, if `UserCreationForm` is a `ModelForm`, I think this will work?  `save`ing a form makes no sense if it is not a ModelForm.

Answer (score 0):

Url.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="registration_form.html")),
```

)

I'm trying to use TemplateView, but nothing happens.
Yes I agree about user instance I will try to fix that.